# Find the limit of $A={\{(\dfrac{\theta-1}{\theta}}, \theta)|\theta=1,2,3,\dots\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, compactness

Question: Find the limit of $A={\{(\dfrac{\theta-1}{\theta}}, \theta)|\theta=1,2,3,\dots\}$?

Here, $\left(\dfrac{\theta-1}{\theta},\theta\right)$ is a point in $\mathbb R^2$ expressed in polar coordinates.

Incomplete answer: At first look, I can say there is no limit point for such a sequence since it goes and goes on and this set of points spirals out toward the circle  $S^1$ ($r=1$), but no obvious point is different than others on $S^1$ to be the limit point (that is the point where this set 'accumulates'). So it doesn't converge at all.

**But**, on the other hand, the disk is compact and therefore limit point compact. This implies that every infinite subset has a limit point. Since $A$ is an infinite subset, so it must have a limit point!

Where does this contradiction come from? And what is the limit of the sequence $A$?

Many thanks.

EDIT - According to the def. of the book: A topological space X is limit point compact if every infinite subset of X has a limit point.

Comment: saw your edit -- the first point still applies. In a compact, every *subsequence* admits at least an adherence value, i.e. has at least one subsequence that converges. It does *not* imply that the sequence itself converges, and there also may be infinitely many converging subsequences.

Comment: @Clement C.: According to the definition of the book: A topological space $X$ is limit point compact if **every** infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point. So $A \subset \mathbb R^2$ has a limit point.

Comment: @AlphaE "has a limit point" means "has **at least** a limit point." If $A$ has infinitely many of them, then in particular it has one.

Comment: @Clement C.: I got it! Thanks a lot for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ does indeed have a limit point $-$ in fact an infinite number of them. Every point on the unit circle is a limit point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your edit.